# Java: Remove a semicolon in a string only if its after a word and quotation mark

Tags: java, regex, csv

Here's my problem:

I need to remove a semicolon in a String but this String comes from a semicolon separated file in excel.

I need to replace a semicolon only if there's a quotation mark after the word.

ie: 
`data1;data2;"This is a duck;";data3;"Here's another duck";`

needs to be replaced by:

```
data1;data2;"This is a duck";data3;"Here's another duck";
```

What is the best way to do this ?

Edit: Here's what i tried:

```
String line = myLine;
line.replaceAll(("\\w*;"),$1);
```

but i can't make it work and I dont think that its the best way to do it. I also tried

```
line = line.replaceall(";\"", "\"");
```

But that doesn't work because it replace

`data1;data2;"This is a duck;";data3;"Here's another duck";`

for

`data1;data2"This is a duck";data3"Here's another duck";`

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself or are you just hoping we'll write the code for you?

Comment: Yea I was about to say please upload what you have in code so we can check it

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion-based.  The "best" way of doing this (or anything) depends greatly on your point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex with [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
/;(?=")/g
```

---

Example :

```
String pattern = ";(?=\")";
String updated = STRING.replaceAll(pattern, "");
```

or

```
String pattern = ";\"";
String updated = STRING.replaceAll(pattern, "\"");
```

Comment: Is this Java ? OP mentioned Java.

Answer (score 0):

If only you want regex :

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile ( "\"(.*);\"");
       String input1 =  "\"This is duck;\"";
       String input2 = "This is duck;";
       Matcher m = p.matcher(input1);
       if ( m.find() )
       {
           input1 = m.group(1);
           System.out.println( "Modified input1 is : " + input1 );
       }
       else
       {
          System.out.println( "input1 is not modified" );
       }
       m = p.matcher(input2);
       if ( m.find() )
       {
           input2 = m.group(1);
           System.out.println( "Modified input2 is : " + input2 );
       }
       else
       {
          System.out.println( "input2 is not modified" );
       }
    }
```

Output :

```
Modified input1 is : This is duck
input2 is not modified
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best but easiest way:

```
 String str = "\"This is a duck;\"";
        str = str.replace(";\"", "\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use regex for that. You should use a csv parser and writer.

For example, here's how you can do it with OpenCSV:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("myCsv.csv"),';');
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("corrected.csv"), ';');

String[] lineTokens;

while ((lineTokens = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    for(String token : lineTokens) {
        token.replace(";", "");
    }

    writer.writeNext(lineTokens);
}

writer.close();
```

If you need to do an operation on a csv, use the right tool. Help yourself and use a csv parser.